# How do I get a MeshRegion from an obj file, or from Geometry3D

Tags: mesh, computational-geometry

How do I read in an obj file as a `MeshRegion` so I can e.g. compute its area?

If I just import the object and try `Area[O]` it tells me it is not a correctly specified region, even for e.g. the StanfordBunny.

Also, how do I turn `Geometry3D` into a `MeshRegion`? For example

```
Area[ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "SpaceShuttle"}]]
```

does not work either.

It seems that geometry has more than one representation in different parts of *Mathematica* - bad.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, you have to first convert it to a `MeshRegion`. Let's take the space shuttle for example:

```
shuttle = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "SpaceShuttle"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now, we discretize it, since it's a `Graphics3D` object, we use `DiscretizeGraphics`:

```
ds = DiscretizeGraphics[shuttle]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now, we can find the `Area` easily:

```
Area[ds]
```

> 177.301907

Similarly for the horse:

```
horse = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Horse"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
dh = DiscretizeGraphics[horse]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We compute the surface area:

```
Area[dh]
```

> 0.0358690432

Comment: Does not always work. `Area[DiscretizeGraphics[Import["somefile.obj"]]]` still give a not correctly specified region error.

Comment: Retried it and it did work. Apologies. I must have typed something wrong.

Comment: I have some cases where Mathematica computes the volume of a closed surface mesh as zero, even though `FindMeshDefects` doesn't find any defects and all the `MeshCoordinates` are points in 3D. I might formulate an MVE and another SE question, but this one seems very closely related.